# Getting Value From Json Data Inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a problem to get the value from json data inside array when the data is more than one.

When my data only one like this:

```
$mydata='[{"firstName":"Ana","height":5.3}]';
```

I can just access the height of Ana by substring-ing it first and the decode it, like this:

```
$mydata= substr($mydata, 1, -1);

$obj = json_decode($mydata);
print $obj->{'height'};
```

The problem is when the data look like this:

```
$mydata='[{"firstName":"Ana","height":5.3},{"firstName":"Taylor","height":5.11}]';
```

How can I get the height of Ana?

```
print $obj->{0}->{'height'}; //doesn't work.
```

Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
 $b_arr=json_decode($mydata,true);
 $b_arr[0]['height'];//0 is index for array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert with **[json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)** and iterate through your array to get your specific data:

```
<?php
$mydata='[{"firstName":"Ana","height":5.3},{"firstName":"George","height":7.3}]';
$json = json_decode($mydata, true);
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
    if($value['firstName'] == 'Ana') {
        echo $value['height'];
        break;
    }
}
?>
```